# pandas.series.str.replace not working with regex patterns loaded from excel

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, replace

I am trying to correct values in a large pandas dataset with other values. In order to achieve this I am using regex pattern and replacement values which are saved for convenience in an excel file.

However using `pandas.series.str.replace(pattern, replace, regex=True)` is not working for me. The values are unchanged.

I have a xls file where one column is a regex pattern and the other the replace value. This file is loaded with pandas read excel into a dataframe df e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd
import regex as re

df = pd.read_excel("replacments.xlsx",dtype=str)
```

| FIND | REPLACE |
| --- | --- |
| \b\s(hello)\b | world |
| ^foo.* | bar |

I tried the following code, however NAMES_CLEAN stays the same as NAMES.

```
for row in df.itertuples():
    data["NAMES_CLEAN"]=data["NAMES"].str.replace(row.FIND,row.REPLACE,regex = True, flags= re.IGNORECASE)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with the regex but with the loop. In essence, only the last regex is being applied. What you want to do is

```py
data["NAMES_CLEAN"] = data["NAMES"]
for row in df.itertuples():
    data["NAMES_CLEAN"] = data["NAMES_CLEAN"].str.replace(row.FIND,row.REPLACE,regex = True, flags= re.IGNORECASE)
```

This way, you update the same column with each successive regex.